# Python Async Error: await only allowed in async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying read files asynchronously, but I am running into an error saying “**await only allowed in async function.**” From my understanding, this error occurs when the `await` keyword is used inside of a function that was not marked as `async`. However, as shown in the code below, I mark the `read_blob` function as `async`

I don’t have any issues running this in .ipynb Jupiter notebook (in which I run the code cell by cell sequentially), but when I try to run it in VSCode in a .py file, it throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
import asyncio
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from io import StringIO, BytesIO


class AsyncContainerClient(ContainerClient):

    async def read_blob(self,
                  blob_name: str,
                  add_blob_name_col=False,
                  add_blob_date_col=False,
                  preprocessing_func=None,
                  zip_regex=r'.+\.gz$',
                  csv_regex='.+\.csv(\.gz)?$',
                  parquet_regex='.+\.parquet$',
                  regex_string=None,
                  **kwargs):

        assert isinstance(blob_name, str), f'{blob_name} is not a string'

        try:
            blob = (await self.download_blob(blob_name))

            with BytesIO() as byte_stream:
                await blob.readinto(byte_stream)
                byte_stream.seek(0)
                return pd.read_parquet(byte_stream, engine='pyarrow')
        
        except ResourceNotFoundError:
            return 0


blob_sas_url = "https://proan.blob"
acc = AsyncContainerClient.from_container_url(blob_sas_url)

test_dirs = ["models1/model.parquet", "models2/model.parquet", "models3/model.parquet"]
res = await asyncio.gather(*(acc.read_blob(f) for f in test_dirs))
```

[image: error_img]

Comment: The line shown in the error isn’t in the code you shared.

Comment: The error fully describes the issue. You should execute that part of code inside an `async` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point to an async program should be `asyncio.run`, you should wrap your code in an async method then call it

```py
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
import asyncio
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from io import StringIO, BytesIO


class AsyncContainerClient(ContainerClient):

    async def read_blob(self,
                  blob_name: str,
                  add_blob_name_col=False,
                  add_blob_date_col=False,
                  preprocessing_func=None,
                  zip_regex=r'.+\.gz$',
                  csv_regex='.+\.csv(\.gz)?$',
                  parquet_regex='.+\.parquet$',
                  regex_string=None,
                  **kwargs):

        assert isinstance(blob_name, str), f'{blob_name} is not a string'

        try:
            blob = (await self.download_blob(blob_name))

            with BytesIO() as byte_stream:
                await blob.readinto(byte_stream)
                byte_stream.seek(0)
                return pd.read_parquet(byte_stream, engine='pyarrow')
        
        except ResourceNotFoundError:
            return 0


async def main():
    blob_sas_url = "https://proan.blob"
    acc = AsyncContainerClient.from_container_url(blob_sas_url)

    test_dirs = ["models1/model.parquet", "models2/model.parquet", 
    "models3/model.parquet"]
    return await asyncio.gather(*(acc.read_blob(f) for f in test_dirs))

asyncio.run(main())
```